# Application.kt in flutter project giving error - Cannot access 'com.google.firebase.messaging.zzf'

Tags: flutter, kotlin, compiler-errors, firebase-cloud-messaging

`My application.kt` file is as below:

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService


class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
    }
}
```

error I am getting:

```
Cannot access 'com.google.firebase.messaging.zzf' which is a supertype 
of 'io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService'.
Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

the line where the error is  `FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)`.

my `android/build.gradle` file have below code for the implementation:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

I have tried to search a lot but still stuck with this issue. whats wrong here ?

Comment: make sure that the classpath dependecies are added to [project]/android/build.gradle file not  app/build.gradle

Comment: Check this link https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging to setup your firebase messaging properly

Comment: the `class dependency` are part of `android/build.gradle` and not `android/app/build.gradle`` as stated before. it was my mistake to put it in the post. app is configured as the `package` states. I have no idea what the error even means !

Answer (score 1):

Try this

In `android/build.gradle` add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'`

In `android/app/build.gradle` add `implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0"`

**OR**

Try this

```
override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin");
    }
```

Comment: I have done all this and initially reverted back to `4.3.2` as that is what the official doc says. don't know whats wrong with plugin not found stuff :/